# Filter STDOUT from a sytem() call and output selective text

Tags: perl, stdout, expect

I have a script that executes different commands in Expect using system().

For most of these I do not need STDOUT to be printed to the user, but in one case I would like just a small portion of the output printed to user. I have used the approach below to redirect STDOUT etc. for all the different commands.

My question is simply, how can I change this so that I can collect all the output in some variable and print just a portion of the output (a string eg. "group number = 12345) to the user?

```
sub execute_cmd {   
my ($q) = @_;
my $para1 = $q->param('para1');
my $para2 = $q->param('para2');
my $para3 = $q->param('para3');
if($transtype eq "A") {
my $cmd = "\/\*ID\=66\*\/OOO LOIPAW\:XXX\=1\,ABC=K\'$para1\,DEF\=ALL\,GHI\=JKLMNO\,PQR\=$para2\;\r";
print $cmd;    
print "<br><br>";
open (TEMPERR, ">&STDERR");
open (TEMPOUT, ">&STDOUT");
open (STDERR, ">nul");
open (STDOUT, ">nul");
system ("./xxx.exp", $cmd);
open (STDERR, ">&TEMPERR");
open (STDOUT, ">&TEMPOUT");
close (TEMPERR);
close (TEMPOUT);
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the output from the system command?

Comment: Yes. In the case above the output from system ("./xxx.exp", $cmd);

Comment: You should also know that this code looks horribly unsafe. You are using what looks like CGI params directly in a system call without any form of validation. What if someone entered `; rm -rf /` in your "para2" param?

Comment: The `system` command does not capture output, use the backticks or `qx()` for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do fancy OUT/ERR redirects to eliminate all output from a command executed by a `system()` call.

Simply use shell redirects:

```
system ("./xxx.exp $cmd > /dev/null"); # Get rid of STDOUT

system ("./xxx.exp $cmd > /dev/null 2>&1"); # Get rid of STDOUT AND STDERR
```

Now, to capture the output, you have 2 options:

1. Use backticks (or `qx()` operator)

   ```
   my $stdout = qx#./xxx.exp $cmd#;
   ```
2. Redirect to a file and slurp in the file:

   my $out_filename = "./something.out";
   system ("./xxx.exp $cmd > $out_filename 2>&1"); # Capture STDOUT AND STDERR
   use File::Slurp;
   my @output = read_file($out_filename);
3. Open a pipe and read from it.

   open(my $output_fh, "./xxx.exp $cmd |") or die "Can't run program: $!\n";
   while my $line () {
       # Do something with $line
   }
   close($output_fh);
4. Use one of standard IO modules. E.g. you can bypass Expect and play with OUT and IN directly via `IPC::Open2`

Comment: I ended up using IPC::Open3.

Comment: @AndyThompson - BTW, I didn't add it to the answer, but pay heed to insecure code comment from TLP. You should be very careful putting random strings into your system calls.